# Printing the unicode of all the letters in a word

Tags: python, python-unicode

I'm stuck on this question:

> user inputs a word, program outputs the unicode of each letter in the word

this is how the input statement would look:

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
```

Supposing the user enters the word "Cat", the output would look like this:

```
C: 67
a: 97
t: 116
```

Comment: Although you've given an example for the output, it doesn't correspond well with the way Unicode strings are described. I suggest something like this [U+0043](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0043/index.htm) [U+0061](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0061/index.htm) [U+0074](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0074/index.htm). That way it is very clear what the input is and the problem reduces to iterating Unicode codepoints (which are numerically the same as the UTF-32 code units, which might be useful if using Python <3.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ord()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

```
word = input("Enter a word: ")
for letter in word:
    print(letter + ': ', ord(letter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example I guess what you try to output is ASCII values of characters. If so you could check ASCII values using python builtin function [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

```
userInput = input("Enter a word: ")

for i in userInput:
    print('{}: {}'.format(i, ord(i)))
```

**Output:**

```
C: 67
a: 97
t: 116
```